# How to aggregate data with respect to time level?

Tags: r, average

I have been trying to work on averaging out the data with respect to month and time.
The data i am using is 6 months (say January to June) with 15 minutes interval in one column and Value at the timeperiod in second column. 
I have averaged out the data from minute interval to Hourly interval using the below mentioned cod:

```
library(xts)

data<-read.csv("C:/Users/naman.nagar/Downloads/JAVA &R/15_Minute_Site_ Avg.csv",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
data$Timestamp<-as.POSIXct(strptime(cognos_data$Timestamp,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"))
data.xts<-xts(x=cognos_data$Wanamaker,cognos_data$Timestamp)
ep<-endpoints(data.xts,"hours")
period.apply(data.xts,ep,mean)
```

The data i is got using the above code is:

```
    2015-12-19 10:15:00 1602
    2015-12-19 11:15:00 1608
    2015-12-19 12:15:00 1590
    2015-12-19 13:15:00 1590
    2015-12-19 14:15:00 1344
    2015-12-19 15:15:00 1338
    2015-12-19 16:15:00 1338
    2015-12-19 17:15:00 1338
    2015-12-19 18:15:00 1338
    2015-12-19 19:15:00 1392
    2015-12-19 20:15:00 1368
    2015-12-19 21:15:00 1302
    2015-12-19 22:15:00 1302
    2015-12-19 23:15:00 1266
    2015-12-20 00:15:00 1248
    2015-12-20 01:15:00 1254
    2015-12-20 02:15:00 1218
    2015-12-20 03:15:00 1188
```

Now from this data,i want the monthly averaged data as:

```
    2015-12 10:00:00 1389
    2015-12 11:00:00 1390
    2015-12 12:00:00 1400
    2015-12 13:00:00 1396
```

Means to say that i get the averaged data of complete December month at hourly level say at 12:00:00, to get the averaged value at particular hour for the complete month.

Please help.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

here is a solution using `dplyr` and `lubridate` packages.
let's say you have data such as:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

# just to make it reproducible
# also added a line at 10:00:00 so that we have at least once more than one value for hour 10

    data <- structure(list(timestamp = c("2015-12-19 10:00:00", "2015-12-19 10:15:00", 
"2015-12-19 11:15:00", "2015-12-19 12:15:00", "2015-12-19 13:15:00", 
"2015-12-19 14:15:00", "2015-12-19 15:15:00", "2015-12-19 16:15:00", 
"2015-12-19 17:15:00", "2015-12-19 18:15:00", "2015-12-19 19:15:00", 
"2015-12-19 20:15:00", "2015-12-19 21:15:00", "2015-12-19 22:15:00", 
"2015-12-19 23:15:00", "2015-12-20 00:15:00", "2015-12-20 01:15:00", 
"2015-12-20 02:15:00", "2015-12-20 03:15:00"), x = c(400, 1602, 
1608, 1590, 1590, 1344, 1338, 1338, 1338, 1338, 1392, 1368, 1302, 
1302, 1266, 1248, 1254, 1218, 1188)), .Names = c("timestamp", 
"x"), row.names = c(NA, 19L), class = "data.frame")

# let's have a look to it
head(data)
#                 timestamp    x
# 1 2015-12-19 10:00:00  400
# 2 2015-12-19 10:15:00 1602
# 3 2015-12-19 11:15:00 1608
# 4 2015-12-19 12:15:00 1590
# 5 2015-12-19 13:15:00 1590
# 6 2015-12-19 14:15:00 1344
# etc.
```

then, we use the pipe below to: i) create new columns year_month (I presume you'll have more than one) + hours, ii) group with by year_month and hours, iii) summarize the average value per group (ie per hour with a given month):

```
data %>% 
   mutate(year_month=paste(year(timestamp), month(timestamp), sep="-"),
          hour=hour(timestamp)) %>% 
   group_by(year_month, hour) %>% summarize(mean_x=mean(x))

    # year_month  hour mean_x
# (chr) (int)  (dbl)
# 1     2015-12     0   1248
# 2     2015-12     1   1254
# 3     2015-12     2   1218
# 4     2015-12     3   1188
# 5     2015-12    10   1001
# 6     2015-12    11   1608
```

Note the value for hour 10.

Is this what you want?

Comment: To some extent, but i do have six months of data and i want monthly data to be averaged on hourly basis. Your answer will group and average out the complete dataset of 6 months for particular hour, however i need the averaged each monthly data on hourly level. Since the data is of 6 months, it will result 144 rows(6 months *24 hours). Does that makes sense?

Comment: was editing my answer when I realized that ;-)

Comment: Thanks very much Vincent! :-)

Answer (score 1):

We could do something like this in `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(mean = mean(value)), by = .(year = format(Timestamp, "%Y"),
                                            month = format(Timestamp, "%m"), 
                                            hour = format(Timestamp, "%H"))]
#   year month hour  mean
#1: 2015    12   10  1602
#2: 2015    12   11  1608
#3: 2015    12   12  1590
#4: 2015    12   13  1590
#5: 2015    12   14  1344
#6: 2015    12   15  1338
```

Comment: Thanks very much @mtoto. :)